# SubscriptionManager.from() Deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-subscriptionmanager

Previously we used to get instance of `SubscriptionManager` using

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager=SubscriptionManager.from(this);
```

but`SubscriptionManager.from(context)` is deprecated in API 28 , what's the new way to get `SubscriptionManager` instance ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can get instance of `SubscriptionManager` using following way

**Java**

```
 SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager= (SubscriptionManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
```

or

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager=getSystemService(SubscriptionManager.class);
```

for API>=23

**Kotlin**

```
val subscriptionManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
```

or

```
var subscriptionManager = getSystemService(SubscriptionManager::class.java)
```

[Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager)

Comment: Thanks for sharing 